# Google app engine intermittent ping failure

Tags: google-app-engine

### Background

We have a google app engine app serving a custom domain (https). The setup has been working for over 2 years now (initially it was http and we shifted to https around 6 months ago). Past one month we are facing intermittent issues of pages timing out/long delays (over 20-30 seconds to load instead of usual 1-2 seconds). When we access our app directly via the appspot url, it works consistently.

### Debugging the issue we realized the following:

- When I ping our appspot link (https://appid.appspot.com), the IP address is **74.125.130.141** and it ping consistently
- When I ping our custom URL (https://www.appdomain.com), the IP address is **74.125.200.121** and ping fails intermittently
- When ever the IP address is pingable, our app works fine. When ever the app is timing out, the ping also fails.
- The failing IP address seems to be one of the IPs in google IP address range - see output of `https://ipdb.at/ip/74.125.200.121`
- The CNAME record for my domain for the host "www" points to `ghs.googlehosted.com`

### Questions

- Has anything changed within google app engine IP mapping in the recent months?
- Is there a way I can force my custom domain to reach a "stable" IP address within the google app engine farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anything changed within google app engine IP mapping in the recent
>   months?

They are actually moving the whole SSL thing out of Google Apps and allowing you to handle custom domains directly from GAE. This was supposed to be completed by June but they are running a little behind.

> Is there a way I can force my custom domain to reach a "stable" IP
>   address within the google app engine farm?

You could set up your App using [managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) that way you'll still be using app engine but from a cloud compute instance with a fixed IP.

Comment: Thanks @jirungaray. Is there a procedure to move my app from Google Apps to GAE directly?

Comment: Not yet. Hopefully they'll release the feature in the coming weeks